# Dell Inspiron 9400 SD card reader not working

Tags: 11.10, dell, sd-card

I'm new in Linux, just installed **Ubuntu 11.10** in a **Dell Inspiron 9400**, everything works fine with the exception of the **SD card reader**, everytime I insert a card the computer doesn't do anything, its like the SD card reader is not there.

I did a `lspci` and it shows the next drivers

03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): **Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394       Controller**

03:01.1 SD Host controller: **Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822       SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter** (rev 19)

03:01.2 System peripheral:    **Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus    Host Adapter** (rev 0a)

03:01.3    System peripheral: **Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller**    (rev 05)

Everytime I insert a memory card, dmesg shows the next

d status 0x600b00

```
[ 2687.227351] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 64
[ 2687.229436] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.229440] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 65
[ 2687.230512] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.230515] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 66
[ 2687.231588] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.231592] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 67
[ 2687.232674] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.232678] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 68
[ 2687.234763] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.234766] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 69
[ 2687.236864] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.236868] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 70
[ 2687.238942] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.238946] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 71
[ 2687.238949] Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0, logical block 8
[ 2687.241028] mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
[ 2687.243104] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.243108] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 64
[ 2687.245212] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.245215] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 65
[ 2687.247298] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.247302] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 66
[ 2687.248389] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.248393] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 67
[ 2687.250476] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.250480] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 68
[ 2687.252617] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
[ 2687.252621] end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 69
[ 2687.254737] mmcblk0: error -110 sending read/write command, response 0x0, card status 0x600b00
```

and more of the same but with different sector number
I'm using **Kernel 3.0.0-12-generic**

By the way, when I was installing it and Ubuntu asks about installation (If I want to install it along with windows or delete something or change the partitions of the HDD) if I go to the window to change the partition of the disc, Linux detects the SD Card (if there's one inserted course).

Any help with this it would be appreciated
-sorry for my English

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I paste here the answer I found on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878064&p=11440361) that worked perfectly for me. I hope this works for you as well (my `lspci` didn't output any sd host controller at the beginning)

1. In terminal type:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/modules
   ```
2. Enter this under the last line:

   ```
   sm_ftl
   ```
3. Restart your computer

Comment: This worked for me on my Lenovo x200 as well. I reported a bug in Launchpad which you might want to follow, [bug 916878](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/916878)