# How can I get my recognized Ricoh SD Card reader working on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, laptop, sd-card, card-reader

On my Asus F3 Series Laptop there is a built in SD Card reader

`lspci` output:

```
09:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
09:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
09:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
09:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
```

It is being recognized, but when I put in an SD Card, nothing happens/is mounted.

Comment: No hints? No one using the same hardware?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution. If anyone stumbles upon this, please try to help.

Comment: answer http://askubuntu.com/a/150891/283843

Comment: Rebooting with a card doesn't work...

Comment: And with `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Comment: nope, still nothing

Comment: output  `lspci -v |grep "Card Reader"`??

Comment: Returns nothing, but see above, it is being recognized, it's just not named card reader

Comment: try to force its reading: `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan"`

Comment: Still not working. By the way, I did verify the reader and the card to be working under windows.

Comment: The card is formatted with FAT32

Comment: Hmm. Insert the card and do `lsblk`.

Comment: It doesnt list anything new before and after putting a card in

Comment: See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/311781).  It's been open since 2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hardware defect, unfortunately.