# Seems Ubuntu cannot read SD cards?

Tags: sd-card

Ubuntu cannot read my SD card.  Many people have pleaded passionately for help with this problem on this board...and no one seems to have received an answer.

I just upgraded to 14.04, but, alas, to not avail.

Put the SD card into the USB slot and nothing at all happens.

This has been a problem with Ubuntu for many years, judging from the history of complaints about it.  It's odd that it cannot be fixed.  Every cheap MP3 player can read one of those SD cards as easy as pie!

Comment: Put it into your pc and give the result of 'sudo fdisk -l'

Comment: How can you put the SD card into an USB slot? USB slot is meant for USB's, while there are card readers meant to uso with SD cards.

Comment: "Seems Ubuntu cannot read SD cards?" yes it can.@dadexix86 usb card reader I assume ;)

Comment: After inserting the SD card, please run the commands `lsusb`, `sudo lsblk -f`, and `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` and [edit] your question to include their output.

Comment: My horrible sd won't even come up in `lsblk` as `/dev/sd*`. so irratating. It cannot be read on other operating systems too. C'MON SanDisk!

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu can read SD cards. If you're having problems consider:

- Can Ubuntu see your SD card reader? `lsusb` aught to tell you if it has connected. If that hangs or doesn't show it though, that suggests that there's a problem. The practical solution is to try another.

  SD card readers are almost famously cheap. I've had some that are so poor they hang BIOS if they're plugged in at boot, or cause USB bus failures if left in too long. I've never experienced such a wide range of suck in any other hardware.
- Can Ubuntu read the filesystem? Does `sudo fdisk -l` show the partition on the SD card? Is it supported by the Kernel? Run `less /proc/filesystems` to see what are supported. Practical solution: pick a better format that your devices *and* your computer can read!
- Is is just not mounting? If you can see the reader and see a mountable partition, try mounting it manually (`sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt` — replace the `sdX1` with the right designation from `fdisk`). There's a fairly complicated udisks/udev chain for mounting these things so perhaps there's a bug in the combination of your reader and format. [This is a known issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95391/how-do-i-mount-an-sd-card) you you step around with:

  ```
  echo 1 > sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
  ```