# UBUNTU 14.04LTS Cannot Mount my SD Card

Tags: 14.04, mount, sd-card

So, I am pretty new to Linux and just installed UBUNTU 14.04 LTS. I've had no issues so far with anything that I could not find answers to here. However, I inserted my 32Gb SD Card into my SD card slot (I've verified on a Windows machine that the card does in fact work) and received the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/cj/4421-0000: 
  Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,
  iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" 
  "/dev/sdb1" "/media/cj/4421-0000"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
  mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

To be quite honest, I have no clue what any of this means. There are other links to this question that I did try but could not get any of them to work.  I have a Dell Inspirion and a clean install of UBUNTU 14.04LTS.  Can anyone decipher this and tell me what I need to do to mount this SD card correctly?

Comment: There is a solution here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/95391/how-do-i-mount-an-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

I think the FS format is in exFAT - a filesystem that I *think* Ubuntu doesn't agree with all too well (though Windows doesn't mind it). Try placing the format of the SD card as NTFS; I haven't had any NTFS problems with Ubuntu (though I *was* using 12.04).

Comment: As much as appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, I do not want change the format of my sd card (not yet anyway).  I have a TON of pics that I just took and need to get them off before doing so.  Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Then there might be something out there in either the Ubuntu Software Center (or whatever they call it now) or in the Synaptic Package Manager that will help you find something to read exFAT filesystems.

Comment: That's where I'm looking now.  If I figure this out, I'll post it for everyone who may also be having trouble!  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, albeit on Linux Mint.

I installed "exfat fuse" and am now able to mount my 128GB SDcard.