# I can't mount my mini SD card

Tags: mount, sd-card

I used `hardinfo` to see if my mini SD card was working, as shown in the image.

[image]

I have tried [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/150891/267521) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/95431/267521).

But I can't mount it.

I try:

```
~$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sde /mnt
```

and:

```
~$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sde /mnt
```

And this error appear:

> mount: no medium found on /dev/sde

My syslog when I insert my SD:

[image]

Do You know how can I mount it?

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: What is it formatted? Also, nice to see a good question by a new user! Hope you stick around here :)

Comment: @Tim I don't know, ntfs i think... Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Looking at your syslog screenshot, there are physical errors while mounting. Is this card working in any other devices?
2. You probably want to mount partition (`/dev/sde1`), not device (`/dev/sde`) with `sudo mount...` command.

You can try to list partitions with `sudo fdisk /dev/sde -l`, but considering the above error of *read sector 0*, there might be a problem, as partition table is held on sector 0.

Comment: No this card is not working in other device. But i want to save more info that was possible. 
I know but in sde1 give me "device /dev/sde1 does not exist"

Comment: `sudo fdisk /dev/sde -l` give me nothing...

Comment: So you want to recover broken card? If so, I recommend using `dd` ASAP, before it will broke even more. And keep looking at syslog (`tail -f /var/log/syslog`) for catching errors.

Comment: Can you help with that?

Comment: Try something like: `dd if=/dev/sde of=/home/your_username/card.dump` (it will take a while). But than again, depending on your estimated value of your data, you can consider contacting some Data Recovery Company, if you decide to, stop using that card and keep it safe before handling it to experts.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I try that but not work for me. I will format the disk.