# How can I format or delete an SD card that is not being recognized?

Tags: mount, sd-card, gnome-disk-utility

I'm in a similar situation to [the one d3vid was in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95391/how-do-i-mount-an-sd-card). I'm trying to reformat my SD card because I believe that's what's making it so hard for my computer to recognize it. Gnome Disk Utility recognizes the SD card but every time I try to format the card it returns a new error. I ran `ls -la /dev/sd*` before and after inserting the card and there was no difference between the outputs. It's like some parts of the computer can recognize the card and others can't...

When I tried to format it as FAT without overwriting the contents disk utility gave the error `Error creating file system: Command-line 'mkfs.vfat -I -n "RASP" "/dev/mmcblk0"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: 'mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
'
stderr: 'mkfs.vfat: failed whilst writing reserved sector
' (udisks-error-quark, 0)`

When I tried overwriting the contents first it gave:
`Error erasing device: Error writing 1048576 bytes to /dev/mmcblk0: Input/output error (udisks-error-quark, 0)`

`lsblk` showed the disk. `sudo blkid` did not. How can I wipe or format it?

Comment: I think you need to run `ls -la /dev/mmcblk*` instead of `ls -la /dev/sd*` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using device mmcblk0p1 (partition 1) on the device to format.  By now, you probably have wiped out the partition table, so first thing, use a disk utility to put a new partition table on it with one partition.  Then you can mount that partition (not the whole device) and format it.

---

The mkfs.vfat -I  command does not make a partition, it just forces the creation of the filesystem as specified on the whole device.  Without the -I, you'd get the error (paraphrasing): "you really don't want to do this".  Now the error you get about writing a reserved sector may be a complaint about putting a filesystem over the partition table (sector 0?).  I could do this on an old card I had, but maybe your card is smarter and rejects such actions.

While such actions as writing to the device instead of a partition on the device should be allowed, It looks like in your case, you have found something which prevents it.  OK, so just do things the expected way and put a partition table on the device, make a partiton, and format it FAT.

Comment: The command should have worked to create a single partition on the device instead as the op used the `-I` flag