# How to make Ubuntu read an SD card?

Tags: usb, mount, sd-card

I've got an SD card reader in my laptop (Ubuntu Focal Fossa).

I've inserted a Kingston SD memory adapter with a micro SD in it.

When I insert it I do hear a "pling" as if it were a USB stick.

It does not appear in the list of external drives, as when I connect a USD stick.

What should I do?

I did **lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0458:6001 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) GF3000F Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And then I did: `sudo lsblk -f`

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/chromium/1229
loop1  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/chromium/1213
loop2  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/9436
loop3  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/9665
loop4  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/1754
loop5  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
loop6  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core18/1880
loop7  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gedit/537
loop8  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
loop9  squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-characters/539
loop10 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
loop11 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
loop12 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/vlc/1700
loop13 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop14 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
loop15 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/postman/117
loop17 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/sublime-text/77
loop18 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop19 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
loop20 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop21 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gedit/605
loop22 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
loop23 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/sublime-text/85
loop24 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
loop25 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop26 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
loop27 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/vlc/1620
loop28 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop29 squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/postman/118
sda                                                                       
├─sda1 vfat           1834-E084                             503.2M     2% /boot/efi
└─sda2 ext4           a0c09570-8697-4d16-9f2f-7801a8d95e90   91.4G    75% /
sdb
```

And then: `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50`

```
[29046.947239] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29046.947246] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Unit Attention [current] 
[29046.947251] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Not ready to ready change, medium may have changed
[29046.947255] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[29046.947261] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947270] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.947350] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.947358] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947361] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.947470] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[29046.947513] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.947523] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947528] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.947668] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.947678] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947683] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.947824] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.947834] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947839] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.947977] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.947987] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.947992] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.948096] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[29046.948140] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.948148] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.948152] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.948293] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.948302] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.948308] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29046.948461] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.948471] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[29046.948476] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[29046.948619] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.948764] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 device offline or changed
[29046.948873]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[29046.954523] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[29047.002033] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29047.002040] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[29047.002048] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 <<vendor>>ASC=0xff <<vendor>>ASCQ=0xff 
[29047.002053] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[29047.002748] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[29047.002761] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[29047.003426]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[29270.766042] kauditd_printk_skb: 62 callbacks suppressed
[29270.766044] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.110:128): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=20524 comm="apparmor_parser"
[29270.766048] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.110:129): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/9665/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=20524 comm="apparmor_parser"
[29271.314599] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.658:130): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.postman.postman" pid=20526 comm="apparmor_parser"
[29271.323954] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.670:131): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.postman" pid=20531 comm="apparmor_parser"
[29271.324358] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.670:132): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=20532 comm="apparmor_parser"
[29271.326252] audit: type=1400 audit(1595442783.670:133): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=20533 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I did do [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/150891/202369): `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Comment: It appears to me that either the media is not formatted, it's formatted in a way that Ubuntu can't understand (maybe exfat), or the SD card is dead.  You should use process of elimination and start ruling things out.

Comment: I've formatted it in a windows machine in Fat32, and still not working.

Comment: Well, does it work in Windows? Why don't you format it in Ubuntu, since you plan to use it in Ubuntu?  The "Disks" application can do this easily (`gnome-disk-utility`)

Comment: I thought about it but it's not recognized by Ubuntu. Even after the fat32 format...

Comment: I am trying to determine, *by process of elimination*, what is *not* wrong with your device. For example, to know if it's not broken, please answer whether or not the device even works on windows?  Have you tried another port? A different SD card? What other things can you rule out?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, it did work as expected in Windows. And I did try a second card, older one, that didn't worked either. Could the port itself be screwed up because of a lack of drivers installed correctly?

Comment: Got it sorted. After doing `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan` one more time it got sorted. :)